# Is it OK to send\receive multiple messages in MPI using one single buffer?

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi

I'm learning MPI and I don't know if it is OK to send or receive multiple messages using the same array.

Every processor needs to send different chunks of its local data to the other processors (and receive their data, too).

Say I have four processors. I use this:

```
MPI_Request sendReqs[4];
MPI_Status sendStats[4];
MPI_Request recReqs[4];
MPI_Status recStats[4];

// locData is an array of integers. I need to distribute chunks of it
// assume I have four processors 
for( i = 0 ; i < 4; i++) {
    send  = locData + indices[2*i]; // location at buffer to start ith send
    count = indices[2*i+1] - indices[2*i] + 1; // how many we send to i 
    MPI_Isend(send, count, MPI_INT, i, rank, MPI_COMM_WORLD, sendReqs[i] );
}
```

similarly, would this be OK?

```
// gatheredData is where each processor stores data it gets form others
// assume I have four processors 
for( i = 0 ; i < 4; i++) {
    start = gatheredData + gatheredIndices[2*i];
    count = gatheredIndices[2*i+1] - gatheredIndices[2*i] + 1;
    MPI_Irecv(start, count, MPI_INT, i, i, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &recReqs[i]);
 }
```

I finish with this this call, to make sure everybody got the data

```
MPI_Waitall(4, sendReqs, sendStats);
MPI_Waitall(4, recReqs , recStats );
```

This does not work -  the processors show they have some junk values inside of gatheredData (as well as some good values).

Comment: This looks a lot like you are trying to implement a all-to-all collective communication yourself. You should be able to use `MPI_Alltoall` and `MPI_Alltoallv` instead. See here: http://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.1/www3/MPI_Alltoall.html and http://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.1/www3/MPI_Alltoallv.html

Comment: Thanks! I think that should do it.

Comment: The answer to your original question is: as long as the different parts to be received do not overlap, using the same buffer is fine. In the end, the whole process memory could be regarded as a single "buffer", so to speak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any point-to-point sending operation can use the same buffer as any other send, since they're not modifying the buffer's contents.

On the receiving side, results are undefined and may lead the program to crash if you don't guarantee that each receiving operation has a buffer that doesn't overlap with those used by any other sends or receives, from the time the receive is posted to the time it's completed.  Your code using `MPI_Irecv` looks OK provided that there's no overlap in `gatheredIndices`.